# GPU stats at container level

Tags: docker, gpu, stat, nvidia-docker

I am using https://hub.docker.com/r/jarkt/docker-remote-api/ to get Docker stats remotely using CURL as follows:

```
curl http://<IP>:<PORT>/containers/<container_name>/stats .
```

Looking for a similar one for getting GPU stats for a specific docker container.

Comment: Do you use `nvidia-docker`?

Comment: Yes, I am using nvidia-docker

Comment: Check https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki/nvidia-docker-plugin#rest-api

Comment: @JanGaraj https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/500 -- "There is no more plugin"